# Getting game ID of psx game

Tags: java, android

I was wondering which is the best way to get the title from a disk image in .iso or .cue+.bin format,
Is there any java library that can do this or should I read from the file header?

**UPDATE:** 
I managed to do it, i was particularly interested in PSX ISOs title. It's 10 bytes long and this is a sample code to read it:

```
File f = new File("cdimage2.bin");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
fin.skip(37696);
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    System.out.print((char) fin.read());
    i++;
}
System.out.println();
```

**UPDATE2:** This method is better:

```
private String getPSXId(File f) {
FileInputStream fin;
try {
    fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    fin.skip(32768);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (fin.read(buffer) != -1) {
        String buffered = new String(buffer);

        if (buffered.contains("BOOT = cdrom:\\")) {
            String tmp = "";
            int lidx = buffered.lastIndexOf("BOOT = cdrom:\\") + 14;
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                tmp += buffered.charAt(lidx + i);
            }
            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            // System.out.println("BOOT = cdrom:\\" + tmp);
            tmp = tmp.toUpperCase().replace(".", "").replace("_", "-");
            fin.close();
            return tmp;
        }

    }
    fin.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start reading after 32768 bytes (unused by ISO9660) in 2048 byte chunks (Volume Descriptor). The first byte determines the type of the descriptor, and `1` means `Primary Volume Descriptor`, which contain the title after the first 7 bytes (which are always `\x01CD001\x01`). The next byte is a NUL (`\x00`) and it is followed by 32 bytes of system and 32 bytes of volume identifier, the latter usually known and displayed as title. See http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~pje/iso9660.html for a more detailed description.

Comment: I was interested particularly in PSX isos, and i found that the title is 10 bytes long and starts at byte 37696

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python version of the OP's answer. it takes the file path as the only argument:

```py
import argparse
import os

def get_psx_id(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fin:
            fin.seek(32768)  # Skip the first 32768 bytes
            while True:
                buffer = fin.read(4096)
                if not buffer:
                    break  # End of file reached

                buffered = buffer.decode('ISO-8859-1')  # Assuming ISO-8859-1 encoding for byte to string conversion

                if "BOOT = cdrom:\\" in buffered:
                    start_idx = buffered.rfind("BOOT = cdrom:\\") + 14
                    tmp = buffered[start_idx:start_idx + 11]
                    tmp = tmp.upper().replace(".", "").replace("_", "-")
                    return tmp

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"File not found: {e}")
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"IO error: {e}")

    return None

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract PSX ID from a file.')
    parser.add_argument('file_path', type=str, help='Path to the file from which to extract the PSX ID.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    psx_id = get_psx_id(args.file_path)
    if psx_id:
        print(f"PSX ID: {psx_id}")
    else:
        print("PSX ID not found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```